# How to run a vbscript in server from windows application vb.net

Tags: .net, vbscript, ssis, server

I am trying to run a vbs script in server from client windows application. Tried WMI management scope but we are having access issue. Unable to get the permissions from server admin . Is there any other way to achieve this ?

The basic concept is to run a SSIS Package from VB Script is there a way to achieve this need to run the package on server only

Comment: you can create a job which can fire SSIS . from VB script just trigger the job.

Comment: Thank you. Development started to create job